# Login sem diferenciar letras maiúsculas e minusculas?

Tags: php, mariadb

Estou a fazer um sistema de login. Na tabela esta cadastrado um user *"UseR01"*, quando o cliente for logar se ele colocar no campo *"user01"* quero que valide assim mesmo.

Aqui vai o código que estou a usar.

```
$Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Name']);
$Pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Pass']);
$PassMD5 = md5($Pass);

$result1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$Name' && userpass = '$PassMD5' LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $result1);
$result3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

if(isset($result3)){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}else{
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

Comment: Qual é o seu banco?

Comment: Está na tag, MySQL.

Comment: MariaDB(mysql), versão PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simpels seria [converter as *strings*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) antes da comparação:

```
$result1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('$Name') && userpass = '$PassMD5' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Se eu fosse usar essa conversao (para as letras ficarem maiusculas), no banco de dados teria que esta "USER01"?

Comment: Na comparação os dois (tanto o dado da base quanto o login do usuário que quer logar) devem estar maiúsculos. Na resposta coloquei os dois (`UPPER(username) = UPPER('$Name')`). OBS: usando a função as letras só ficam maiúsculas na comparação, não é alterado na base.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Converta o nome de usuário em minúsculas
$username = strtolower($Name);

// Use LOWER () para converter o nome de usuário em minúsculas
$result1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username)='$username' && userpass = '$PassMD5' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 3):

Como você não sabe como está sendo armazenado, utilize das `COLLATIONS CASE INSENSITIVE` para efetuar esse trabalho:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username COLLATE utf8_general_ci = '$Name' && userpass = '$PassMD5' LIMIT 1";
```

Para acentuação é utilizado também o `latin1_general_ci`.

[Aqui há a lista de `collations` suportadas pelo `MariaDB`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/supported-character-sets-and-collations/).

Comment: Resolvido Obrigado a todos :)

Comment: @João se alguma das respostas ajudou a resolver o problema, marque-a como resolvida. Caso tenha dúvidas sobre, dá uma lida em: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)